# Pip / boto problems - ImportError: No module named boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, aws-cli, boto

I want to get boto3 working in a python3 script. I can execute aws commands from the cli.

1. After updating pip, it doesn't run with sudo rights unless I use the absolute path: `/usr/local/bin/pip`. Without sudo rights it works. I have no idea why it doesn't run under sudo, which it did before updating, as `/usr/local/bin` is in PATH.
2. Should I run pip under sudo or not?
3. I installed boto3, but still get `ImportError: No module named 'boto3'`. This is when I execute a script that runs python3. But it seems that boto3 is installed for python2.

Output:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install --upgrade boto3
Requirement already up-to-date: boto3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

**How do I get boto3 working with python3?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the best way to deal with multiple python versions is to isolate them using `virtualenv`

This article covers it's basics and would give you a good overview
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: Thanks. That fixes question 3. I still have to use the absolute path for pip, but that's not a major problem. And I'm still wondering whether to run pip as root or not.

Comment: virtualenv by default lets you run it as regular user, as it installs packages inside an env and accessible for your current user

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ubuntu, try this out:-

```
sudo apt install python-boto3
```

Should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
brew postinstall python3
```

worked after a 'brew upgrade' caused this error to come up.